# Interpolating array of integrals

Tags: integration, interpolation

I have an array of integrals, that I want to interpolate and differentiate to get result array. What kind of interpolation should I use to get a reasonably smooth output? (e.g. the output is derivative so linear interpolation will result in steps)

I can provide 2nd array of tangents for every node - if it helps to lower computational cost.

Comment: Do you have any specific integrals?

Comment: It can be any numbers, say a continue wave integrated at specific points